# Could not find databaseChangeLog node with include

Tags: yaml, liquibase

I`m trying to include **changeset.yaml** file into **changelog.yaml** for Liquidbase.

***file changelog.yaml***

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: migrations/changeset.yaml
```

***changeset.yaml***

```
changeset:
  id: 1
  author: vlad
```

Getting this when executing update

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not find databaseChangeLog node
```

Any ideas why? Thanks.

UPDATE:
Seems to be the same if im using xml format.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

changeset.yaml must contain databaseChangeLog
So in my case i should have had this:

***changeset.yaml***

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: vlad
```

Documentation wasn`t really helpful. Found answer [here in github](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/master/liquibase-core/src/test/resources/liquibase/parser/core/yaml)

Comment: If someone will struggle with `parsing error`, please, check if you have `changeSet` instead of `changeset`. Hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I've already declared the node properly, but it turns out I forgot to create spaces for include which should be -(space)include and -changeset which should be           -(space)changeSet in my YML files . Also the spelling for one of my YML file which was a databaseChangelog which should have had a capital L and should be databaseChangeLog. Afterall those mistype syntaxed, the error was gone alright.